# Knex js opening multiple inactive sessions for a given user in oracle db

Tags: node.js, session, oracle11g, sails.js, knex.js

I am working on a web application with [knex js](http://knexjs.org/)  along with [oracle DB](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html) on a [sails js](http://sailsjs.com/) platform. In my project, I have the limitation that only 10 session users can be opened simultaneously irrespective of them being active or not.

While working on [knex js](http://knexjs.org/) with [oracle DB](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html), I found that [knex js](http://knexjs.org/) open up many inactive sessions for the same user on my AWS RDS instance. Screenshot attached below.

[image]

Due to this my API written on the [sails js](http://sailsjs.com/) framework breaks with the following error

```
ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit
```

My question is that is there a way to reduce or remove the invalid sessions and make the session limit to 10 in [knex js](http://knexjs.org/).

**Note:**

My **node version** is *6.10.0*. Also, **my oracle database** is on *11g* and my **sails js** version is *0.12.9*.

Comment: Can you specify which adapter you are using? Please provide a URL.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I am using the knex js with node-oracledb npm module.

 Node-Oracle Db npm
 https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb

Comment: Sails.js uses adapters to connect to databases. Which Sails.js adapter are you using?

Comment: @DanMcGhan I am not using any inbuilt sails adapters .

Comment: Could you share your pool settings etc. Provided info is not enough to say anything why your problems are happening.

Comment: Are you running this locally or on some cloud platform?

Comment: @MikaelLepistö i am not providing any pool settings in my knex js

Comment: @lascort I am running it on AWS RDS Instance

Comment: check if there's something like a keepalive request pinging your server, that might generate unwanted sessions

Comment: @shubhamagiwal92 try to create simpler (few lines of javascript using knex) program which reproduces your problem. With your description there is still no way to figure out why that is happening. With default knex pool settings, knex won't take more than 10 db connections... so you must be  using knex wrong or your DB session limit (connection limit for single database user) is less than 10 or you are using some other db clients with same credentials to connect DB at the same time.